# replacing prime index from the list with given output

Tags: python, indexing

Write a function which takes a list of unique positive numbers and returns a subset of that list by removing those elements which occur at prime positions in the original list.

Example:

Input:

```
[2, 567, 34, 35, 8, 77]
```

Here, element 2 is in 1st position, element 567 is in 2nd position and so on..

Output:

```
[2, 35, 77]
```

Here, elements 567, 34 and 8 are removed as they occur in prime positions namely 2nd, 3rd and 5th.

Comment: Please mention the code and the steps you took.
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hint: look up `enumerate()` and `is_prime()` in `Python`.

Answer (score 1):

Using is_prime and enumerate

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    for integer in range(2, int(num ** 0.5)+1):
        if num % integer == 0:
            return False
    return True

lst = [2, 567, 34, 35, 8, 77]
# Use list comprehension to filter out numbers with prime index
# use start argument to start enumeration at 1 (0 is the default)
# for i, v in enumerate(lst, start = 1) provides a list
# of tuples of index and value for each element in list lst
answer = [v for i, v in enumerate(lst, start = 1) if not is_prime(i)]
print(answer) # Output: [2, 35, 77]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l2 =[]
for index, value in enumerate(l1):
    #print(index)
    if index > 1:
        # Iterate from 2 to n / 2  
        for i in range(2, index): 
            if (index % i) == 0: 
               print(index, "is not a prime number") 
               l2.append(value)
               break
        else:
            print(index, " is a prime number") 
    else: 
        print(index, "is not a prime number")
        l2.append(value)
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

#function to check if a number is prime or not

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    
    elif num == 2:
        return True
        
    #to check if num is divisible by any number in range [2, num/2]
    for i in range(2, int((num/2) + 1)):

            if (num % i == 0):
                return False

    return True

def get_subset(numbers: list):
    subset = []

    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        if not isPrime(index + 1):
            subset.append(number)

    return subset
```